# What does a vertical square bracket and number indicate on a piano score?

Tags: piano, notation, fingering

[image: score excerpt where A# and C# not have a vertical square backet and number 1 adjacent]

Does it indicate to play the A# and C# with the same finger (a horizontal style thumb?). I’m not sure that’s possible!

Does the notation have a name?

Comment: This chord is specifically addressed in part 3 of the duplicate's accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it does mean to play them both with the thumb. It's possible for some people, not for others. If you can't do it, the answer in the other post shows other ways to play it.